# Resource related to real world measurment vs simulated data for RACH LTE

Tags: reference-request, lte

I am trying to find resources where I can study the comparison of the various features of the Random access channel in LTE using simulated and real-world measurement data. It would be great if you can point towards any resources.

Comment: what kind of features are you referring to? Because, as stated, you're basically asking for "what is the wholeness of wireless channels on which LTE works", and honestly, that might be far broader than you mean to ask! Maybe start with what you want to *do* with that (library-filling) knowledge!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is a part of the study I will be doing in the future for my thesis. I would like to study the received Prach signal (zc sequence) and how it differs from the transmitted signal, timing offset estimation, etc using simulated and real-world measurement data.  Mainly, I am looking for a starting point, so that I can have an idea of how to approach this kind of problem. Therefore, any literature related to this kind of study will be helpful in my pursuit.

Comment: ah, so the fact that it's LTE, or that it's PRACH doesn't matter (for now), what matters is the effect of the wireless channel on Zadoff-Chu sequences?

Comment: Yes, that is right. And, compare the effect using the simulated data and real-world measurement. And, then identify the gaps between these two datasets.

Comment: but: a *good* simulation should be indistinguishable with respect to the things you care about from reality. So, you'd need to say "this *specific* simulation", because otherwise someone will just have a better simulation... So, do you have a specific channel simulator in mind?

Comment: Yes, AWGN and TDLC

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question and work all these comments you gave here into that? Because how it now looks is that you care about how wireless channels aren't like simplistic channel *models* (a mathematical channel model is not the same as a simulator!), which LTE doesn't even assume in their pure forms itself. That's now yet another pivot in the direction this question is taking, so color me a bit confused :)